# How to make an API endpoint render interactive chart

Tags: python, api, charts, frontend, backend

I know the classic approach when backend send json to front end, and front-end render the view, but how to communicate when backend plot an interactive chart (using python Flask, and pyecharts for plotting), no json returned to front-end here, and I don't want to send the data for front end and make it responsible for plotting.

the function used to plot is

```
bar.render_notebook // this will draw an interactive chart in jupyter notebook like this
```

or

```
bar.render       // this will generate HTML file in the root folder with the interactive graph renderd
```

I tried `return bar.render` and `return bar.render_notebook` in the function called by the API call `/api/interactive`
but it didn't work

So how to communicate with front end in this case?

Comment: “*I don't want to send the data for front end and make it responsible for plotting.*” Er, why not? This isn’t a particularly common design pattern; can you give us a bit more color as to the requirement that gives rise to this design decision?

Comment: I read that if we do so (pass data for front end to plot), this will cause you to change both the front and back if you want to edit something, and I thought that what if we want our servers to be responsible for that, not clients computers. Anyway I didn't know that this is the standard away, I just thought that there is a way I don't know for backend to communicate with frontend in such cases